# create scatter plot

Tags: bash, scripts, functions, gnuplot, plot

file (1. arg) will create (scatter plot) for n. column (x-axis, 2. arg) and m. column (y-axis, 3. arg)

function is called **myfun sourcefile 1 3** for scatter plot of 1. and 3. column from file sourcefile.

```
#!/bin/bash/gnuplot

myfun(){
 plot "$1" using $2:$3
}
myfun sourcefile 1 3
```

In gnuplot> plot sourcefile using 1:3 works perfectly. I want it to run inside the function. How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest using a shell [here document](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) in this case

```
#!/bin/bash

function myfun {
cat << EOF | gnuplot -p
plot "$1" using $2:$3
EOF
}
```

Then

```
myfun sourcefile 1 3
```

Comment: thanks, but anytime I execute it, I get the script on the screen. No graph :/

Comment: Thanks soo much :) It now somehow works :D :D :D :D :D :D :D

Comment: what is "E0F" ? and why do we need it ? also  <<

Comment: @MartinYeboah did you read the wikipedia link? `EOF` is just a `END_TEXT` marker. You can use pretty much any string: `EOF` (end of file) or `EOD` (end of data) are just common choices

Answer (score 2):

I really do not know what kind of script is that one. Where did you find it? `.../bash/gnuplot` seems that someone is getting really confused.

But if you have the file with the data, call it `sourcefile`, with the structure

```
whatever  x-data y-data
whatever  x-data y-data
whatever  x-data y-data
```

you can have a scatter plot of column 3 versus column 2 entering `gnuplot`, and at the prompt using:

```
plot "sourcefile" using 2:3
```

(Although your script *seems* to be doing `plot "sourcefile" using 1:3`, in contrast with your description, and without quotes which is a syntax error in gnuplot unless `sourcefile` is a variable containing the name of the file).

I recommend you to read http://people.duke.edu/~hpgavin/gnuplot.html

Comment: Thank you! I can create the scatterplot in gnu-plot like how you suggested. But I want to execute it inside the function too.. :(